# JavaFX: Group is not centered within VBox

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'd like to center a group of nodes within a VBox and scale the group if it exceeds the bounds of the parent VBox.

I tried the following setup: A ScrollPane contains a VBox, which should center a Group of Nodes (e.g. Circles, Lines, etc).

The Nodes are added dynamically: `myCustomPane.getContentPane().getChildren().addAll(ellipse, line)`

Unfortunately neither the (red) group is centered nor visible on the window. However I do see the (orange) ScalablePane, the (blue) VBox, and all the nodes.

```
public class ScalablePane extends ScrollPane {

    private Property<Group> contentPaneProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    public ScalablePane() {
        setContentPane(new Group());
        setPannable(true);
        setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        setFitToHeight(true); // center
        setFitToWidth(true); // center
        setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange;");
    }

    public final void setContentPane(Group contentPane) {
        contentPane.setManaged(false);
        contentPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBox.setManaged(true);
        vBox.getChildren().add(contentPane);
        vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

        setContent(vBox);
        contentPaneProperty.setValue(contentPane);
     }

     public Group getContentPane() {
        return contentPaneProperty.getValue();
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
      ScalablePane pane = new ScalablePane();
      Circle circle = new Circle(200, 40, 20);
      Circle circle2 = new Circle(100, 150, 20);

      pane.getContentPane().getChildren().addAll(circle, circle2);

      Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.sizeToScene();
      primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

**Update: drag-support added**

I tried to add drag-support for my nodes, so I can check when the inner pane is rescaling. I also changed the Group to a simple Pane so I can make the boundaries of the inner pane visible. Unfortunately the inner pane (red) does not snap to the child nodes. How can I force the content pane, to take the size of its children and rescale if it's size exceeds the parent boundaries?

```
public class ScalablePane extends ScrollPane {

  private final Pane contentPane;
  private final Scale contentScaleTransform;

  public ScalablePane() {
    contentPane = new Pane();
    contentScaleTransform = new Scale(1, 1);

    initializeScrollPane();
    initializeContentPane();
  }

  public void initializeScrollPane() {
    setPannable(true);
    setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
    setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
    setFitToHeight(true); // center
    setFitToWidth(true); // center
    setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange;");
  }

  private final void initializeContentPane() {
    contentPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    VBox.setMargin(contentPane, new Insets(10));
    vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    vBox.setManaged(true);
    vBox.getChildren().add(contentPane);
    vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

    setContent(vBox);

    contentPane.layoutBoundsProperty()
        .addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {
          @Override
          public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observable,
              Bounds oldValue, Bounds newValue) {

            double parentWidth = getContentPane().getParent().getLayoutBounds()
                .getWidth() - 10;
            double parentHeight = getContentPane().getParent().getLayoutBounds()
                .getHeight() - 10;

            if (parentHeight > 0 && parentWidth > 0) {
              if (newValue.getHeight() > parentHeight
                  || newValue.getWidth() > parentWidth) {
                computeScale();
              }
            }
          }
        });
  }

  public void computeScale() {
    double realWidth = getContentPane().prefWidth(getWidth());
    double realHeight = getContentPane().prefHeight(getHeight());

    double leftAndRight = getInsets().getLeft() + getInsets().getRight();
    double topAndBottom = getInsets().getTop() + getInsets().getBottom();

    double contentWidth = getWidth() - leftAndRight;
    double contentHeight = getHeight() - topAndBottom;

    double scaleX = contentWidth / realWidth;
    double scaleY = contentHeight / realHeight;

    double scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    getContentScaleTransform().setX(scale);
    getContentScaleTransform().setY(scale);

    getContentPane().resize(contentWidth / getContentScaleTransform().getX(),
        contentHeight / getContentScaleTransform().getY());
  }

  public Pane getContentPane() {
    return contentPane;
  }

  public final Scale getContentScaleTransform() {
    return contentScaleTransform;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Main extends Application {

  private double dragOriginalSceneX;
  private double dragOriginalSceneY;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
      ScalablePane pane = new ScalablePane();
      Circle circle = new Circle(200, 40, 20);
      Circle circle2 = new Circle(100, 150, 20);
      addDragSupport(circle, pane);
      addDragSupport(circle2, pane);

      pane.getContentPane().getChildren().addAll(circle, circle2);

      Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.sizeToScene();
      primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }


  private void addDragSupport(Circle node, ScalablePane graphPane) {
    node.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
      dragOriginalSceneX = e.getSceneX()
          / graphPane.getContentScaleTransform().getX();
      dragOriginalSceneY = e.getSceneY()
          / graphPane.getContentScaleTransform().getY();
    });

    node.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
      Circle circle = (Circle) e.getSource();
      circle.setManaged(true);
      double eventX = e.getSceneX()
          / graphPane.getContentScaleTransform().getX();
      double eventY = e.getSceneY()
          / graphPane.getContentScaleTransform().getY();

      double offsetX = eventX - dragOriginalSceneX;
      double offsetY = eventY - dragOriginalSceneY;

      double newX = circle.getCenterX() + offsetX;
      double newY = circle.getCenterY() + offsetY;

      circle.setCenterX(newX);
      circle.setCenterY(newY);

      // remember last coordinates
      dragOriginalSceneX = eventX;
      dragOriginalSceneY = eventY;
    });
  }
```

Comment: I can get your class to compile. It has errors.

Comment: `contentScaleTransform = new Scale(1, 1);` is showing an error: Where is it declared?

Comment: Sorry, I just posted an excerpt of the class, as the whole scale functionality is not so important for the issue. I forgot to remove the line, where the Scale is defined.

Comment: Start here -> [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks, I updated the example code.

Comment: I am going to recommend you try [this](https://github.com/miho/ScaledFX) or [this](http://mihosoft.eu/?p=429)

Comment: Thank you. I checked them out, but the JFXtras ScalableContentPane has one drawback. If I drag my nodes to the left or to the top, the pane does not rescale. I'd like to drag my nodes freely as long as the nodes stay within the bounds of the VBox. If they leave the VBox, the inner Pane should scale.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have this working the way you want except scaling give it a try let me know if it works also you cannot add css to a group here is an example of things a group can do if you are looking for more 
information https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#group

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class ScalablePane extends ScrollPane {

//    private Property<Group> contentPaneProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private Group contentPane = new Group();

    public ScalablePane() {
        setContentPane(/*new Group()*/);
        setPannable(true);
        setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        setFitToHeight(true); // center
        setFitToWidth(true); // center
        setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange;");
    }

    public final void setContentPane(/*Group contentPane*/) {
//        contentPane.setManaged(false);
        contentPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBox.setManaged(true);
        vBox.getChildren().add(contentPane);
        vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

        setContent(vBox);
//        contentPaneProperty.setValue(contentPane);
    }

    public Group getContentPane() {
        return contentPane;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that I can't apply styles to a Group. So I assumed, that the box isn't there.

Comment: I extended my example with drag support and a scale functionality. But there are still two issues: The content pane does not take up the size of its children, and the child nodes do leave the boundaries of the content pane, if I drag them around.